# Migrate Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().addFunction to Vaadin Flow

Tags: javascript, migration, vaadin

I have the following Vaadin 8 code:

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().addFunction("getDocument", args -> {
    ...
    //java rest call
    ...
});
```

getDocument  is called in javascript code.

```
window.documentSign = function(signerUrl,procedure) {
    ....
    getDocument(signerRequest.responseText,procedure,messageId);
    ....
}
```

How can I migrate this piece of code to Vaadin Flow 14?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addFunction` in Vaadin 8 provides a way for JavaScript to send data back to the server.

I guess this isn't a one-time case that can be handled by returning a value (or a Promise) through `executeJs`. I also guess this case isn't related to a component class where you can define a `@ClientCallable` method in Java and access that from JS through `element.$server`.

What remains is firing a custom DOM event on the `<body>` element and listening for that event on the `UI` element through Java.

Firing a event from JS:

```js
document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('event-name', { detail: 'String from JS' }));
```

Listening for the event in Java:

```java
ui.getElement().addEventListener("event-name", event -> {
  System.out.println(event.getEventData().getString("event.detail"));
}).addEventData("event.detail");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("getDocument", <args as varargs>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think the question might be not clear. It is updated.